# Postgresql WITH clause in crosstab queries

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, crosstab

I create a large query as a Common Table Expression - month_index using `WITH` clause. Is it possible to refer this Common Table Expression in a crosstab query's source sql?

When I did gets an error 
relation "month_index" does not exist

```
WITH month_index AS
(
      SELECT ...
)
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB(
   'SELECT rowid AS row_name,
   CONCAT(''m'',monthno) AS category,
   nic5dindex AS value
   FROM month_index',
   '*<categorysql>*')
AS ct(..)
```

I use Postgresql 9.3.

Comment: the outdated and unsupported version 8.3 did not have common table expressions. But I think that even with a supported version that does have CTEs the crosstab function won't be able to access the CTE. You will need to create a view that you can reference in the SELECT statement that you pass to the `crosstab()` function.

Answer (score 4):

You want to have your CTE fully contained within the crosstab.
More like this... you can have a CTE in a crosstab, but not vice-versa.

```
    SELECT * 
FROM CROSSTAB(
$$
    WITH month_index AS
    (
       SELECT rowid AS row_name,
       CONCAT(''m'',monthno) AS category,
       nic5dindex AS value
       FROM source_data_table
    )
    SELECT * FROM month_index 
,
   '*<categorysql>*'
$$   
   )
AS ct(..)
```